# How to decode a LDAP {crypt} password

Tags: perl, ldap, decode, crypt

I'm studying a migration from an old LDAP to a new database.
Today I just found that the passwords are all saved as {crypt} passwords and the new system does not support that.

Is it possible to decode the {crypt} passwords (in PERL if possible) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, crypt implements a one way hash.

However, you have the hash values and (hopefully) the salt. Whenever a user submits a password, it's encrypted with the same salt, and if the hashes match, the user is authenticated.

In general, it's a very bad practice to have human readable passwords, but you don't need to read a raw input password to authenticate a user.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be *no*. The whole point of hashes such as crypt is that you can't do that. However, if it's using the old-fashion unix `crypt()`, it's often actually quite brute-forceable (it's rather weak cryptography). Question is, should you really want that.

This is sounding like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though. What LDAP servers are we talking about, and what formats do they support? There's a reasonable chance there's some kind of overlap that can be used for migrational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If implemented correctly a password stored as `crypt` can not be decoded into cleartext because it is not encrypted but hashed.

Depending on your target system you might be able to migrate the hashed passwords "as-is", but you have to determine which hash was used and if the same is supported by your target system.

You need to disclose more about the LDAP server and the database you use.